# Upgrading Android ADT to 15 says logcat(deprecated)

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I upgraded my eclipse with ADT plugin from 10.0 to 15.0 because I was getting an error when I imported a project "This project requires you to upgrade the ADT to 14.0 and above" When I upgraded the ADT, logcat is deprecated.Any idea why? Window ->Show View ->Others ->logcat(deprecated). This is how it occurs. I can still see the log...no issues with that,but I am apprehensive about its longevity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see two entries in the Others list: LogCat and LogCat (deprecated). The latter has the bugdroid icon; the former has the new lolcat-based icon.

[image]