# What is the difference between LogCat and LogCat(deprecated)?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, logcat

I use eclipse to develop apps. When I goto eclipse's menu window->show view->other, I find two items nameed "LogCat" and "LogCat(deprecated)". What is the difference between LogCat and LogCat(deprecated)? I find when an application is running, they show the same logs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104318/upgrading-android-adt-to-15-says-logcatdeprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LogCat was provided in ADT 4.0 or above, just add some new features. LogCat(deprecated) was the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated means that at some point it will most likely stop functioning, you can still use whichever one you prefer until that happens .

Answer (score 0):

I used both `logcat` and `logcat(deprecated)`, and i did not found any difference except font and some details :)

Answer (score 0):

Use of deprecated is the same like in any language. It's old and won't get support or won't have any improvement in that. In this case, theoretically Logcat should have or will have more/better features.